# Error while calling member function

Tags: c++, user-interface

Hi I have just started using C++ today, and I am working on checkboxes. I have tried using `CheckBox1->Checked` in an if statement or whatever, but it isn't working.

The error is:

> Error 2 error C2227: left of '->Checked' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

**EDIT:** The Code is:

```
    void function ()
{
 if (1001->Checked)
 {
             Sleep(2000);
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you try actually reading the documentation of whatever it is you're trying to work with? (MFC?)

Comment: Please post some code and also mention which GUI framework you're trying to work with.

Comment: In Win32, you can do : if (SendMessage (GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_YOUR_CONTROL), BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0) == BST_CHECKED)

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing some of your code, it's very difficult to offer targeted assistance.

However, that error message usually comes about because the item you're de-referencing is not a pointer.

Check to ensure it's of the correct type. It should be something along the lines of:

```
tCheckBox *CheckBox1;
```

One possibility is that you've declared it not as a pointer to the checkbox but as a checkbox itself:

```
tCheckBox CheckBox1;
```

Note the lack of the asterisk there that would otherwise mark it as a pointer. In that case, you would use `CheckBox1.Checked` rather than `CheckBox1->Checked`, if it's allowed by the framework (this isn't standard C++ since that beast has no concept of GUI libraries).

If that doesn't help, please post the code so we can offer better suggestions.

*Update:*

```
if (1001->Checked) ?????
```

1001 is *not* a pointer - it's not a variable of any description, it's an integer constant.

You need to declare and use a variable of some description. First step is, I think, to read up on the documentation for your framework and/or get some sample code that does compile and work, basing your initial work of that.

Comment: I'm guessing 1001 is the resource IDC of the control in MFC.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CButton::GetCheck()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tba1y6f(VS.80).aspx) to determine the state of the checkbox - like so...

```
CButton* pButton = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECKBOX_RESOURCE_ID);

if ( BST_CHECKED == pButton->GetCheck() )
{
  // button is checked
}
```

Comment: One of the low points of MFC is that it doesn't know the type of a window. You must typecast the results of GetDlgItem to CButton*, because otherwise it won't assign it to a button pointer.